# IE8 not running search field on enter and tripping javascript validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, compatibility

Internet Explorer is at it again.

I am trying to do some simple validation on my search box, but if you hit the enter button instead of the submit button, it runs the JavaScript error, "Please enter valid search words."

Here's my forum:

```
 <div id="search_box">

<div style="float:left;">
    <form id="mini-search-form" name="searchform" action="/search/" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="searchaction" value="search" />
        <input type="hidden" name="profile" value="gameChangerAll" />
        <div id="search_input">
            <input type="text" name="query" id="query" placeholder="Search or Quote" size="10" onfocus="clearInput(this.id);" />
        </div> 


        <div id="search_button">
            <input type="submit" name="sitesearch" id="sitesearch" value="Go" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And then here is my validation:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery("#mini-search-form").submit(function() {
    var match =/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.exec(jQuery('#mini-search-form #query').val());
  if(!match){
    alert("Please enter valid search words.");
    jQuery('#mini-search-form #query').focus();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
});
```

Comment: "trips the JavaScript error"... you get an error?  What error?  Show us the error message.  What *exactly* happens in IE8?

Comment: I made an edit to better clarify. It trips the alert("Please enter valid search words.")

Comment: what do you mean by "it trips" javascript error?

Comment: @PixelReaper: That's not an "error", that's part of your code.  What are you typing in the box?  Does clicking the button trigger the alert?

Comment: IE8 causes the JavaScript error to run, and does not perform the search--regardless of if the search had proper search terms, if the user hits enter, it will not run.

Comment: Clicking the submit button with wording inside of the search box runs the query just fine, but if the user hits the enter button with text inside of the search box, it runs the error in my script, alert("Please enter valid search words.")

Comment: To clarify.... you mean, when you press enter with text in the searchbox, you get different results than when you click submit with the same text in the searchbox?

Comment: Not sure why, but the `jQuery('#mini-search-form #query').focus();` is what's messing it up.  Remove that, and you'll see that the form does not submit.

Comment: Yes exactly. The user has to hit the actual submit button for the query to be ran correctly, he or she cannot his the enter button.

Comment: @KevinB: Yes.  I just tested this and if you type invalid text in the box and click the alert appears and the form is not submitted.  If you hit enter, the alert is triggered *and* the form is submitted.

Comment: So, what would be a fix to this issue for IE8? Gotta love good 'ol IE.

Comment: @PixelReaper: Remove the `jQuery('#mini-search-form #query').focus();` line :-)  If you really need that, try putting it in a `setTimeout`: `setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#mini-search-form #query').focus(); }, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but it's the `.focus()` line that's causing your problem.  If you move that to be inside of a `setTimeout`, it fixes the problem.

```
jQuery("#mini-search-form").submit(function() {
    var match =/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/.exec(jQuery('#mini-search-form #query').val());
    if(!match){
        alert("Please enter valid search words.");
        setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery('#mini-search-form #query').focus();
        }, 0);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
});
```

Comment: One second, have to update the document and sync it with the server. I'll report back once everything is online.

Comment: @PixelReaper: It seemed to work for me (I'm running Windows XP with IE 8 in a VM) :-)

Comment: Hey just to follow up after getting this on the server, this didn't solve the issue. So, we just have abandoned the validation for IE8. Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't duplicate this issue, but I did notice your match doesn't accept spaces.

```
$("#mini-search-form").submit(function() {
var val = $('#query').val();
if(!val.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\ ]+$/)){
    alert("Please enter valid search words.");
    $('#mini-search-form #query').focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/SJXGm/